# Is there a way to continue on error while still getting correct feedback?

Tags: github-actions

I'm trying to find a way to achieve the following functionality:
Whenever a step fails, it will show that it failed (will provide correct feedback) but will still continue to other steps.

At the moment, failure causes the step to stop:

[image: Step's failure prevents next step from starting]

I've seen the most popular suggestion is to use continue-on-error, but that seems to make the step's conclusion 'Success', and will not show it failed unless you go into the logs.

[image: Failed step appears to be successful]

In the screenshot above, the "Secrets" step failed, and yet it appears to be successful unless entering the logs.

When reading [this thread](https://github.community/t/continue-on-error-allow-failure-ui-indication/16773),  I came to suspect this feature might not exist yet in GH actions.

I've also tried using conditionals for each step, and/or for the job.
For example, I've tried:
`if: ${{ success() }} || ${{ failure() }}` - this simply did not provide the needed functionality, the step failed and the next step did not start.

`if: succeeded() || failed()` - took this syntax from the GitHub community thread above, but it generated a syntax error (which makes sense, since it isn't compatible with the syntax specified [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions)).

To conclude, I'm looking for a way to make steps that fail indicate they failed, and still make the workflow continue to the next step.

Comment: instead of `succeeded() || failure()`, try [`always()`](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#always). Use this on the subsequent steps that need to run regardless of if a previous step fails

Comment: always() seems to work, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a github-actions step, even if the previous step fails, while still failing the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858429/how-to-run-a-github-actions-step-even-if-the-previous-step-fails-while-still-f)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To my surprise, and thanks to @smac89 for suggesting it - adding `if: always()` seems to do the trick.
I'm still wondering why `if: ${{ success() }} || ${{ failure() }}` failed, but the solution seems to work for the moment.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: i think `if: ${{ success() || failure() }}` would work. Note only one set of braces. From my reading of the docs `if: always()` runs when the job when cancelled as well as if it passes or fails.

Comment: this doesn't work for me, the step still fails and the next steps get cancelled

Comment: Regarding the comment by @knocte , you need to add the line with 'if' to each step _after_ the failing step. See this answer for a worked example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58859404/2792414

Comment: thanks for the clarification @hermann-gruber, I might give this a go; but it's such an ugly solution nonetheless, I hope GitHub implements a better of way of showing warnings or something

Answer (score 21):

The `continue-on-error` is indeed popular, and part of the reason is perhaps that you can set it for each step, or for the whole job. I’m not sure you are aware of this, and this solution was the answer I was looking for.

##### Example 1

This will continue all steps, if either fails:

```yaml
Job:
  MyRun:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    continue-on-error: true
    
    steps:
      - name: Step One
        run: curl --fail -o dates.csv https://doesnotexist.com/dates.csv
      - name: Step Two
        run: date >> dates.csv
```

##### Example 2

This will only continue if “Step One” fails, it will break and stop if e.g. “Step Two” fails:

```yaml
Job:
  MyRun:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - name: Step One
        run: curl --fail -o dates.csv https://doesnotexist.com/dates.csv
        continue-on-error: true
      - name: Step Two
        run: date >> dates.csv
```

**NOTE:** If you have a failing build step it depends on where you put continue-on-error whether you get a red or green icon for that failed job:

- if you put `continue-on-error: true` in the job's metadata, you'll get a red icon (Example 1)
- if you put it in one of the steps, you'll get a green icon (Example 2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, but I believe `continue-on-error: true` still marks the failing step as "succeeded" with a faux green checkmark. What the op (as well as myself) is looking for is to continue execution of the workflow on error but show that the step failed with a red X.  The other answer, [using always()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62112985/552792) achieves this, but it involves putting `if: always()` on every subsequent step, so it's not without its own headaches.

Comment: Sure, you're right! Hence, it's why I said "I’m not sure you are aware of this, and this solution was the answer I was looking for" :) There are both with their limitations.

Comment: **UPDATE** Seems they updated it, no green icon anymore.

Comment: @MSBerends do you know in which version it was updated?

Comment: No not a clue. Do you still get the green icon then, like if it seems that everything went well?

Comment: I do. green icon even if the step fails (but declared as `continue-on-error: true`)

Comment: Weird, and very inconsistent of GitHub...

Comment: To anyone who says there is no false succeeded icon, please just link your run so that we can see it ourselves. Here is my run: https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/try-actions/actions/runs/8460192545/job/23177927473 All three steps have a gray check mark indicating success even though the second step (with continue-on-error) exits with non-zero.

Answer (score 6):

Just adding on to this old conversation:

1. The behavior has changed.  My job marked with `continue-on-error: true` *does* show a "failure" icon, not a faux "success" icon.  The workflow continues on afterward.
2. If a job punts to an external workflow via `uses:`, the `continue-on-error` must go in the jobs in the *external* file.  It cannot go on the job in the *main* workflow.
   That is, the following gives a syntax error:

```
jobs:
  my_continue_on_error_job:
    uses: ./.github/workflows/other_workflow.yml
    continue-on-error: true
```

It fails with:

> The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main_workflow.yml (Line: 201, Col: 5): Unexpected value 'continue-on-error'

It worked when I moved the `continue-on-error` into the jobs in the other_workflow.

Comment: The implication that the behavior has changed is not correct regardless of what the icon is. Citing the [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error) : 

"Prevents a job from failing when a step fails. Set to true to allow a job to pass when this step fails."

Therefore your job will not be considered failed regardless of what the icon is.

Answer (score -2):

Just in case this helps someone else, and because I struggled to find the right answer to this myself.

It turns out the answer is sort of staring you in the face, but it's just confusing because of the way the documentation phrases things, I think.

But, in short, all you need to do is set

```yaml
  strategy:
    fail-fast: false
```

at the top level. there is no need to set `continue-on-error` at each step, that's a distraction.

see [this answer to another SO question: "Marking GitHub actions workflow as failed if a single job fails in matrix"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841204/366221).

Comment: this only works for a matrix

Comment: The question is about continuing steps of a job and not about jobs of a matrix.