# Marking GitHub actions workflow as failed if a single job fails in matrix

Tags: github-actions

When running a GitHub Actions matrix workflow, how can we allow a job to fail, continue running all the other jobs, and also mark the workflow itself as failed?

Below in this image, you can see that the workflow passes even after a job failed. We need to mark the workflow as failed in this case.

[image: Image of our workflow results]

Here is the small portion of my workflow yaml file.
continue-on-error line will continue the workflow even if a job fails but how do we get the whole workflow marked as failed?

```
   matrixed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    continue-on-error: true  
    timeout-minutes: 60
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: myDir

    strategy:
      matrix:
        testgroups:
          [
            "bookingpage-docker-hub-parallel",
            "bookingpage-docker-hub-parallel-group-1",
            "bookingpage-payments",
          ]
```

I did find this [unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66869407/fail-github-actions-workflow-if-some-jobs-with-continue-on-errortrue-have-fai), but this is about steps and we need to know about jobs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`fail-fast: false`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstrategyfail-fast) for the `strategy` and don't set `continue-on-error` on the job.

```
  matrixed:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 60
    defaults:
      run:
        shell: bash
        working-directory: myDir

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        testgroups:
          [
            "bookingpage-docker-hub-parallel",
            "bookingpage-docker-hub-parallel-group-1",
            "bookingpage-payments",
          ]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @riQQ . So, the problem is because of continue-on-error. This line is making the whole workflow as passed even if a single job passes.