# Github action matrix job stops while one of strategy completes

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners, github-actions-runners

I am trying to run a job on multiple os using matrix strategy. my code is below -

```
strategy:
  matrix:
    os: [ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-20.04, self-hosted]
runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
steps:
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
```

However if one of the triggerd job complete with success or failure, all other paralell jobs on remaining os from matrix get terminated automatically.
How can I change this behavior?

I am expecting my all jobs from matrix to keep running till end.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/70841204/4042883

adding below attribute helped -

```
strategy:
      fail-fast: false
```