# How can you configure a step to run based on a dependent job's outcome?

Tags: github-actions

I'm working on getting our Playwright tests into GitHub Actions. We have 2 sets of tests, API tests and E2E tests. The E2E tests are configured with a matrix of OS and browser, so we end up with X*Y total runs for that. I'm trying to configure a notification job which will run after all API and E2E tests are completed. I've got the notification job working, however, it's always running the success step, even if any of the dependent tests fail.

This is the configuration for the notification job:

```
run-api-tests:
 ...
run-e2e-tests:
 ...
notification:
  needs: [run-api-tests, run-e2e-tests]
  runs-on: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
    - name: Slack Notify Failure
      uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.25.0
      if: always() && (contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') || contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled'))
        ... send notification ...
    - name: Slack Notify Success
      uses: slackapi/slack-github-action@v1.25.0
      if: always() && !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') && !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled')
        ... send notification ...
```

So basically, if any of the runs are cancelled or fail, it should send the failure notification, else send the success notification. It's my understanding that the `needs.*.result` will give a list of the results of the jobs listed in the `needs` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Getting the correct notification to run

You don't directly show it, but based on your notification job configuration I suspect that you use `continue-on-error: true` or something similar on the other jobs that might fail, to always run your notification step.

`continue-on-failure` seems to be somewhat buggy. If I do this in the notifications job:

```
      - name: Echo debug
        run: echo ${{ needs.test.result }}
```

It will print `success` even if the previous job was failure.

However, if I don't use `continue-on-error`, but use `if: always()` on the *job* level, I can still continue to the notification job after failing tests AND the result of `{{ needs.test.result }}` is `failure`.

```
  notification:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    needs: test
    if: always()

    steps:
    ...
```

### Still running matrix jobs

You said your earlier jobs are matrix jobs, so there is probably a reason for your `continue-on-error`. However, according to https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/45546 you can just use `fail-fast: false` strategy to achieve the same result without affecting the build result.

See also: [Marking GitHub actions workflow as failed if a single job fails in matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70830094/marking-github-actions-workflow-as-failed-if-a-single-job-fails-in-matrix)

```
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
```

### Bonus

You also don't need to use `always()` on the step level, that's kind of misleading even. This works:

```
      - name: Slack Notify Failure
        if: ${{ contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') || contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled') }}
        run: echo "Failure"

      - name: Slack Notify Success
        if: ${{ !contains(needs.*.result, 'failure') && !contains(needs.*.result, 'cancelled') }}
        run: echo "Success"
```

Comment: Yes, your assumptions were correct! These suggestions solved my problems, thanks so much!