# Prevent Github Action Step from Getting canceled

Tags: github-actions

### Background

I'm running terraform in a GitHub action. When the GitHub action gets canceled, terraform exits and doesn't save the work it's done to the terraform state. This is a mess to clean up, I would like to prevent terraform from being killed or this workflow job from being canceled entirely.

If there was an opposite command to `concurrency.cancel-in-progress` that prevented in-progress runs from being canceled, this would work. I can find no such thing though.

Comment: Why does it get canceled?

Comment: @rethab A developer clicked cancel.

Comment: Perhaps this would help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67218068/225291