# Github action: how to upload log on test failure then stop

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to make a Github Action that runs a "make check" step.  If it succeeds, it should archive the test log as an artifact and continue to the next step.  If it fails, it should upload the test log as an artifact then stop.

What I have is

```
jobs:
  build:
    steps:

    # Then a bunch of steps to download Cygwin and run autoconf and make, then...    

    - name: make check
      run: make check
      shell: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -o igncr '{0}'
    - name: Archive test logs
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: logs
        path: test.log
    - name: make install
      run: make install
      shell: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -o igncr '{0}'
```

Whether "make check" succeeds or fails, I'd like "Archive test logs" to run. But then "make install" shouldn't run if "make check" failed.

I did try adding 'continue-on-error: true' to the 'make check' step so that it always runs the "Archive test logs" step, which works. But then it runs 'make install' unnecessarily

Comment: Did you try removing the `continue-on-error: true` from the `make check` step and add an `if: success() || failure()` to the `Archive test logs` step?

Comment: That seems to work.  I hadn't tried it because, from the docs, I had guessed that the run would keep going.

Comment: I found that this question was asked before here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858429/how-to-run-a-github-actions-step-even-if-the-previous-step-fails-while-still-f

Comment: Great! I'm glad you found a solution. I'll suggest closing the question as it's duplicated.