# Make github actions not delete its cache after a failed run

Tags: github-actions

I have a github action that installs a bunch of build tools (taking ~20 minutes) and then runs some tests with them. Unfortunately, my tests are not being run correctly, but this is a story for a different day. My problem is that when Github Actions fails, it seems to not cache the build tools I installed previously, which makes debugging my issue take extremely long, since I need to wait 20 minutes each time. Is there a way I can mark some specific things as still being cached inspite of my pipeline failing?

Here's how I cache things:

```
      - uses: actions/cache@v2 
        name: Cargo Cache      
        with:
          path: ~/.cargo
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('Cargo.toml') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-cargo-${{ hashFiles('Cargo.toml') }}
            ${{ runner.os }}-cargo
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run a github-actions step, even if the previous step fails, while still failing the job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58858429/how-to-run-a-github-actions-step-even-if-the-previous-step-fails-while-still-f)